# File passed to Pipeline B and Read and append content of file shared by pipeline A in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, encryption, syntax, jenkins-pipeline, appendfile

Kindly suggest some pipeline syntax

Pipeline A -->should call pipeline B

1. File A
2. File will be passed to pipeline B
3. send some string parameter
4. read the append content by pipeline-B

Pipeline B:

1. read content of file shared by pipeline A
2. will echo string param and content of file
3. append some lines at the end of file A

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note that while your question may be understandable, this is not a code writing service; your question is actually **multiple questions** (one for each point). There should be documentation you can refer to for guidance here; else, try asking about a specific part of your program that you are confused about.

Comment: Thanks Connor.Let me clarify the question,
parameterized pipeline with files can be passed as input and return files from the same